# Weird network behavior with TP-Link TL-PA7025P Powerline adapters

Tags: router, ping, powerline-networking

I bought four **TP-Link PowerLine Adapters** ( two **TL-PA7025P KIT** ) 1000 Mbps.
By replacing four Netgear 200 Mpbs Powerline Adapters I got a faster and more reliable connection. Great!

But sometimes, when a computer (directly plugged to one of the adapters) is downloading, I experience a network problem which seems to be related to downloading through a peer 2 peer protocol (Steam or World Of Tank for example). Here's the network problem:

- When it happens, **no computer can ping the router** ( SFR Box NB6 @ 192.168.1.1 ) **through the Ethernet connection**.
- Computers **can ping the router through WiFi** connection.
- Because the router/gateway is unreachable, Internet can't be reached.
- Computers **can ping each others through the router** ( PC1  <--Ethernet--> router <--PowerLine--> PC2 )
- Communication with the router **works again after about 5 minutes**

I know this seems router related, but **this never happened with Netgear Powerline** adapters.
The router's IP adress seems blacklisted for 5 minutes, but I'm not really sure what's going on.

I tried so many things that it would be too long to write here. 
Any information or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Are you getting any different color lights on the adapter when this occurs?

Comment: No, the three lights on the adapter stay green. When this happens I can ping any other computer through the powerline adapter except the router.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the powerline adapters when this occurs? ive read a few times that steam has had issues with powerline adapters and its fix is to reset the connection after you close a steam game and open it back up.

Comment: I tried to reset it, but because it fixes itself after about 5 minutes even without touching anything, I'm not sure reset helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this by replacing the router with another model.